# Access vba moving to a record by changing a combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have been having a problem with this for a while and can't seem to crack it.

I have created a separate form (frmAdd) to add a new record. What I want it to do is when the record has been created to

1. Add the new record to the combo box  **- done**
2. Get the combo box to display to the new record **- done**
3. Have the bound form move to the new record  **- not working**

The item is definitely in the list because it shows up, but the form still displays the previous record. I have used refresh and requery but to no avail.
the reason there is a call to the After_Update procedure is that it won't run on its own (which may be a clue)

I have attached the code and form images below. You will see on the Display form that one record is displayed in the Combo Box but a different record is on the rest of the form. I would be grateful for any help

```
Private Sub CboFind_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    If Not IsNull(Me.cboFind) Then
        'Save before move.
        If Me.Dirty Then
            Me.Dirty = False
        End If
        'Search in the clone set.
        Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst "[ClientID] = " & Me.cboFind
        If rs.NoMatch Then
        Else
            'Display the found record in the form.
            Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdd", , , , , acDialog
    If NewRec = True Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        strSQL = "SELECT clientid,sname,fname,address,suburb from TBLCLIENTS where sname = '" & pubSName & "' AND fname = '" & pubFName & "' AND address = '" & pubAddr & "' AND suburb = '" & pubSuburb & "'"
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        ID = rst!ClientID
        Me.cboFind.SetFocus
        Me.cboFind.Value = ID
        Call CboFind_AfterUpdate
        Me.cboFind.Requery
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

[Add Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTnji.jpg)

[Display Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoTf9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got it to work. The solution for me was fairly messy. It involved manually calling the cbofind_AfterUpdate subroutine but after a set of requeries as shown below. Thanks guys for your help. It was most appreciated.

```
    If NewRec = True Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        strSQL = "SELECT clientid,sname,fname,address,suburb from TBLCLIENTS where sname = '" & pubSName & "' AND fname = '" & pubFName & "' AND address = '" & pubAddr & "' AND suburb = '" & pubSuburb & "'"
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        ID = rst!ClientID
        Me.cboFind.Requery
        Me.cboFind.SetFocus
        Me.cboFind.Value = ID
        Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[ClientID] = " & Me.cboFind
        Me.Form.Refresh
        Me.Form.Requery
        Me.cboFind.Requery
        Call CboFind_AfterUpdate
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks in form's recordset and clone of this recordset are different in common case. Use the recordset directly instead of cloning:

```
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[ClientID] = " & Me.cboFind
```

instead of

```
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ClientID] = " & Me.cboFind
    If rs.NoMatch Then
    Else
        'Display the found record in the form.
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: This was a lot less code but unfortunately made no difference. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the RecordsetClone is correct, but you probably don't have the ID from the combobox.

Look up the record directly and/or requery the combobox sooner:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If NewRec = True Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT clientid,sname,fname,address,suburb from TBLCLIENTS where sname = '" & pubSName & "' AND fname = '" & pubFName & "' AND address = '" & pubAddr & "' AND suburb = '" & pubSuburb & "'"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    ID = rst!ClientID
    Me.cboFind.Requery
    Me.cboFind.SetFocus
    Me.cboFind.Value = ID

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    Debug.Print "[ClientID] = " & ID
    rs.FindFirst "[ClientID] = " & ID
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        'Display the found record in the form.
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: The problem remains the same in that the combo box contains the new record but the rest of the form points to a different record. Thanks anyway

Comment: If the ID is correct (double-check that using Debug as shown), then something else is going on.